# TextView disappearing after button click

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and I am using version 2.3 of the same.I am learning the concept of intent.I have created 2 activities:Apples and Bananas.Each have a textView and a Button.Apples has an editText.User inputs in editText and clicks the button.then Bananas opens and the textView of Bananas change to .

My problem is :after clicking button,textView in Bananas is disappearing.I have found that this is due to line of code in java code for Bananas activity:

```
bananasText.setText(applesMessage);
```

But I do not know what changes should I make.
following is code for both activities.

```
//code for Apples activity
package com.awani.intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class Apples extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apples);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    //create instance of intent class
    //this tells the app that the following is the activity which we want to launch on click of the button
    Intent I= new Intent(this,Bananas.class);

    //Refer to the input textfield in the activity
    final EditText applesInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.applesInput);
    //get the inuput from user
   String userMessage=applesInput.getText().toString();
    //pass this info to the net activity which will appear afterr this click
    I.putExtra("applesmessage",userMessage);//this method takes info from current activity in the form of k ey-value pair


    //launch the activity
    startActivity(I);

}
}


//code for activity Bananas
package com.awani.intent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;



public class Bananas extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bananas);

    //we need this class to accept the extra infromation passed to it by some other activity
    Bundle applesData=getIntent().getExtras();//this extra information is stored in applesData
    //test if the data is null or there is something(so that to avoid error)
   if(applesData==null){
        return;
    }
    //now as error is taken care of,move forward
    String applesMessage=applesData.getString("applesMessage");//in the variable applesMessage we are storing the string we got from user by passing the key which we passed in putExtra method
    //refer to the textview in the banana activity
    final TextView bananasText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bananasText);
    bananasText.setText(applesMessage);//we change the text Bananas to the text which was input by user

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    //create instance of intent class
    //this tells the app that the following is the activity which we want to launch on click of the button
    Intent I= new Intent(this,Apples.class);

    //launch the activity
    startActivity(I);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bananas activity change the key to get the value, because in First activity you are sending the key as "applesmessage" and in Bananas you are receiving as "applesMessage"

```
String applesMessage=applesData.getString("applesMessage");
```

to

```
String applesMessage=applesData.getString("applesmessage");
```

Comment: crap!I am really sorry that I put such a doubt here...this was silly mistake and I spent like 3 hours in finding the error...Thanks though :)